# Slice tensor in Keras Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, slice, tensor

For example, I have tensor with shape `(None, 2, 100, 100, 1024)` and I want to split `2` into `1` and `1` so that I have 2 tensors with rank of 4 `(None, 100, 100, 1024)`. How can I do this using Keras Tensorflow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.split()`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 2, 100, 100, 1024))
splitted = [tf.squeeze(t, axis=1) for t in tf.split(tensor, 2, axis=1)]
print(splitted[0].get_shape().as_list(), splitted[1].get_shape().as_list())
# [None, 100, 100, 1024] [None, 100, 100, 1024]
```

To concatenate back:

```py
# manipulate here ...
splitted = [t[:, None, ...] for t in splitted]
res = tf.concat(splitted, axis=1)
print(res.get_shape().as_list()) # [None, 2, 100, 100, 1024]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works !!! And after I manipulate the value of each tensor, how can I reshape back to `(None, 2, 100, 100, 1024)` ?